# Restrict REST API access

Tags: rest, web-services, web-applications

I have a public facing API that returns some data, internally using the Google Maps API Service. This API is mostly for internal purposes right now, invoked through the web application.
However, I wish to restrict the usage of this API i.e. it should only be invoked from my Web Application ( or mobile app) when a user (non-registered) browses it. An http request directly to this API should not be authorized.

I cannot use API keys since the webapp flow should work for non-registered users as well.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't have another server tier?  Enterprise systems often have a firewall between public APIs and internal services.  If you are clever, though, you can e.g. run your internal APIs on a different port and block public access to that port on you firewall/ACL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using HTTPS, any security mechanism is flawed, because it can be replicated. IMHO, you could add a HTTP header (e.g. "Request-source: YourApp") and check for its existance in your API.

Of course, once it's documented somehow, anyone can mimic this header. But if you use HTTPS and create a header that's unknown for other people, you prevent this from happening.

Comment: using https for such a use case looks like an overkill to me. Using the header is a nice idea, but I believe i'm not going to resort to SSL for some time in the future

Comment: As long as there's no one sniffing around your network communication, you don't need HTTPS.